# Neural network input layer for a game with variable sized state

Tags: neural-network

I (think I) can understand how the inputs may be structured for a neural network playing a game like chess or go where the next action of the player depends on inputs of a fixed size. However there are simpler games where the state visible to the player is of a variable size (i.e. in the case of [uno](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uno_(card_game)), a simple card game, the player may have any number of cards in their hand, and the next move may depend on the cards that have already been played of which there is no set amount).

Are these types of games incompatible with a neural network? If not, what might the input layer look like? And if so, what are the alternatives?

Answer (score 0):

You can implement everything you want with Neural Networks/Expert systems/AI, but what you have to consider if this is the better tool to do the job.

When you work with this kind of approach the problem in most of the cases is how to encode the input in a proper way to archive the best result when you evaluate your AI.

Yes, you can implement chess and uno with AI, but you have to think first on how you can code your inputs and on how you think when you play the game.

Doing this with AI it's much more difficult than use a traditional approach.

If you google implement Chess AI you will find a few implementations, some using electromagnetic field intensity, other one using functions to rank moves.

The question is what you want to archive, a game developed with an AI or to code a good chess game?.

Do you want to use the tool because it's cool or because you think that it can fit on the problem context

Comment: I want to use the tool because its cool (well really to learn about it). I'm not entering the computer Uno wold championships. ;)

Comment: well then i encourage you to start with http://robocode.sourceforge.net/ , much easier and fun than chess, and with more online resources http://www.ciaranmccann.me/java-ai-robocode/